# How to get photos of following users' photos using flickr API?

Tags: flickr

In Flickr, in your home page you can see all the photos from the users you are following. How can I get this data using the Flickr API? I couldn't find a proper method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flickr.contacts.getList](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.contacts.getList.html) to get a list of a user's contacts, which is more or less the list of people that the user is following.